# Extract string based on pattern in shell script

Tags: shell, awk, cut

I am writing a script and stuck at a point where I have to extract a string based on the pattern.
I have tried using awk and cut but not be able to get the correct outcome.

These are 3 lines in my file and I am looking to extract 2nd last column

**expected output**

1. MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49
2. alert_manager
3. MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49

I tried the below one which is the closest I get but it extracts only for few lines not all of them.

```
awk  -F"," '{print $10}' Filename.txt
```

**File Content**

```
./subsearch_nested_fa89eeb0810630b9_1626351940.6/metadata.csv:2:"read : [ admin ], write : [ admin ]",admin,"MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49",300
./scheduler__nobody_YWxlcnRfbWFuYWdlcg__RMD5922da96313b0bb40_at_1626282000_20762/metadata.csv:2:"read : [ splunk-system-user ], write : [ splunk-system-user ]","splunk-system-user","alert_manager",86400
./subsearch_admin__admin_TXhNb25pdG9yX01hcnZlbF9QSTQ5__search12_1626351937.20757776_1626351938.1/metadata.csv:2:"read : [ admin ], write : [ admin ]",admin,"MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49",300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this shorter `awk`:

```sh
awk '{gsub(/^.*,"|",.*/, "")} 1' file

MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49
alert_manager
MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49
```

So similar `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^.*,"|",.*//g' file
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk -F'"' '{print $(NF-1)}' file
MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49
alert_manager
MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following code. Set field separator as `,` and remove starting, ending `"` from 2nd last field and finally print it.

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$(NF-1));print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If the field separator is a comma and the values can be optionally wrapped in double quotes, for the example data you might set the field separator to a comma between optional double quotes using `"?,"?`

```
awk -F '"?,"?' '{print $(NF-1)}' file
```

Output

```
MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49
alert_manager
MxMonitor_Marvel_PI49
```